# Parse two JSON objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

When i send API i'm getting **JSON** response like this.

> {"ABC":[{"ID1":"response","ID2":"response","ID3":"response","ID4":"response","ID5":"response"},{"ID1":"response","ID2":"response","ID3":"response","ID4":"response","ID5":"response"},{"ID1":"response","ID2":"response","ID3":"response","ID4":"response","ID5":"response"}],"status":"OK","count":3}
>
> {"XYZ":[{"id1":"response"},{"id1":"response"},{"id1":"response"}],"status":"OK","count":3}

Here i'm getting **two JSON** objects in the response. How to store this data in MutableArrays.

My code is...

```
//Getting data from server through JSON approach ...
self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.urlReq= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://MyApiName"]]];

self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlReq completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        if (!(data == nil)) {
            
            self.loginDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"data : %@", data);
            NSLog(@"Login Dic : %@", [self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"]);

            if (!(self.loginDic == nil)) {
                
                self.integer = [[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] count];
                
                if ([[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"] && (!(self.integer == 0))) {
                    
                    self.ID1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    self.ID2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    self.ID3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    self.ID4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    self.ID5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    
                    for (int i=0; i<self.integer; i++) {
                            
                        [self.ID1 addObject:[[[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID1"]];
                        [self.ID2 addObject:[[[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID2"]];
                        [self.ID3 addObject:[[[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID3"]];
                        [self.ID4 addObject:[[[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID4"]];
                        [self.ID5 addObject:[[[self.loginDic objectForKey:@"ABC"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID5"]];                                
                    }
                    
                    NSLog(@"%@", self.ID1);
                    NSLog(@"%@", self.ID2);
                    
                } else {
                    
                }
                
            } else {
            
            }
            
        } else {
            
        }
        
    }];
    
    [self.dataTask resume];

}
```

I'm getting data, but I'm getting `loginDic = null`.

Comment: First of all the JSON you posted is not a valid one. Second thing is your code doesn't make any sense because the keys in your JSON and the keys in your code is different.

Comment: Are you sending it that way from the server?

Comment: @Midhun MP I'm sorry I edited above code ...

Comment: @iOSDeveloper: Can you please update the JSON too ? It's still invalid (You can validate your JSON here: http://jsoneditoronline.org). But if you are getting result from server like that, that's the reason why you are getting null while parsing JSON.

Comment: I'm getting error. Yes, thank u...

Comment: Use swiftyJSON and Alamofire libraries to make your life much easier.

Comment: @ Moaz Khan thank u...

Comment: Add the error reference in serialization to check what is the issue why you were not getting anything

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Your json string having some issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you get  AB , its array of Dictionary

you can easily use this **valueForKeyPath** like:

```
   NSArray * AB = @[@{
                      @"ID1":@"response",
                       @"ID2":@"response",
                      @"ID3":@"response",
                      @"ID4":@"response",
                      @"ID5":@"response",
                     },@{
                @"ID1":@"response",
                @"ID2":@"response",
                @"ID3":@"response",
                @"ID4":@"response",
                @"ID5":@"response"
                }];



    NSArray * ID1 = [AB valueForKeyPath:@"ID1"];
    NSArray * ID2 = [AB valueForKeyPath:@"ID2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to receive two JSON objects at a time?

The JSON you show is indeed two valid JSON encodings concatenated. If your server is doing this and there is nothing you can do to fix that then you can try to fix it yourself:

1. Any occurrence of `][`, `}{`, `]{` or `}[` with any amount of white space between the two characters is the end of one JSON encoding and the start of the next. Construct an `NSRegularExpression` to find these sequences and replace them with the same close/open bracket/brace combination but with a comma (`,`) in between them.
2. Add a single `[` at the start and a single `]` at the end.

These two steps will converted your concatenated JSON encodings into a JSON array of the individual encodings. Now parse and process as usual remembering you first need to index into the outermost array to access the particular JSON response before your index into the response to access the elements you need.

HTH